# How to restore auto IDs in transaction rollback

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am not sure if this is a behavior of the `DB` or the `application`. If a transaction fails at a point where some records had already been added into a table with auto-generated IDs, say ID `22`, and there's `rollback` is there a way to re-use the ID `22`? That way the table is restored to what it was -- even with regards to **next auto ID** -- before the failed transaction.

Here is the code I have been running with the point of failure indicated:

```
transaction
{
    grC = ORMExecuteQuery( "FROM Relation1 WHERE somid=#form.someid#" );
    if( ArrayLen( grC ) GT 0 )
    {
        oGR.id = [];
        for( i =1; i LTE ArrayLen(grC); i = i + 1 )
        {
            grCNew = EntityNew( "Relation2" );
            grCNew.setFirstName( grC[i].getFirstname() );
            .........
            EntitySave( grCNew );
            ORMflush();
            oGR.id[i] = grCNew.getID();
            EntityDelete( grC ); //<<--- **POINT OF FAILURE**
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent losing IDs in `Relation2` whenever there's transaction rollback due to a failure to delete corresponding entity/record in `Relation1`? Is it the database I should change or my application?

Comment: Yes `Relation2` is `InnoDB` and the inserted records are remove alright, but the next time a successful insertion happens, it is at prev-ID + 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MySQL.com site, there will still be gaps. Not sure what your use case is but the gaps shouldn't be a problem. If you need consecutive numbers then you should either auto-generate them in another way (e.g. outside MySQL in PHP or other language). Good luck.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll take a look at the reference.

Comment: Remember, auto_increment is a mechanism to create unique keys (for discriminating otherwise identical rows and joining, etc.). Another option if you need to 'fill in the gaps' is to create a temporary table with its own auto_increment and do a subquery select to populate it from the original table.